# How to Flight_Name instead of Flight_ID?

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

Sir I have two tables.. (i-e)

```
(1) fare(Fare_ID, Flight_ID, Departure_Arrival_Station, Fare
(2) flights(Flight_ID, Flight_Name, No_Of_Seats.
```

I have foreach all data from *fare table and it gives me Flight_ID, which is correct. Now how should i will display the flight_Name instead of Flight_ID on the screen.. I try on it, this is my code. Thank you..

> My Model

```
function getFlightName()
{
  $this->db->select("flights.Flight_ID, flights.Flight_Name");
  $this->db->from('flights');
  $this->db->join('fare', 'fare.Flight_ID = flights.Flight_ID');
  $query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
}
```

> My Controller

```
public function fare()
{
  $data['tt'] = $this->db->get('fare')->result();
  $this->load->model('time_tbl_model');
  $data['flt_nm'] = $this->time_tbl_model->getFlightName();
  $this->load->view('front/fare', $data);
}
```

> My View

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"   id="dataTables-example">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="center">Fare_ID</th>
        <th class="center">Flight Name</th>
        <th class="center">Departure_Arrival_Station</th>
        <th class="center">Fare</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php foreach ($tt as $s): ?>
        <tr class="odd gradeX">
             <td><?php echo $s->Fare_ID; ?></td>
             <td><?php echo $s->Flight_ID; ?></td>
             <?php foreach ($flt_nm as $ff): ?>
                <td><?php echo $ff->Flight_Name; ?> </td>
             <?php endforeach; ?>
             <td><?php echo $s->Departure_Arrival_Station; ?></td>
             <td><?php echo $s->Fare; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

> This is output on the screen, when i executed it.
>   snag.gy/zLt2d.jpg
>   [image]

Comment: `flight name` filed should come to `fare` filed ??

Comment: Yes @abdullah, i want to get flight name instead of flight id

Comment: so change above data `td` in ur code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw your edited post and your image and I believe what you are trying to achieve is like the example of result in the end of this post.

Besides other problems, you're creating some messy stuff when using model code inside controller function. You should separate that, otherwise you're not correctly using MVC pattern.

That said, here's an example of what I would do:

**Your model**

```
public function getFlights()
{
   $this->db->select('f.*, GROUP_CONCAT(fl.Flight_Name SEPARATOR "<br/>") AS `flight_names`')
            ->from('fare AS f')
            ->join('flights AS fl', 'fl.Flight_ID = f.Flight_ID', 'INNER')
            ->group_by('f.Flight_ID');

   return $this->db->get()->result();
}
```

**Your controller**

```
$this->data['flights'] = $this->your_model->getFlights();
```

**Your view**

```
<?php foreach($flights as $flight) { ?>

<td><?php echo $flight->Fare_ID; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $flight->flight_names; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $flight->Departure_Arrival_Station; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $flight->Fare; ?></td>

<?php } ?>
```

This will reproduce something like:

```
Fare_ID | Flight Names | Departure Arrival Station | Fare
          Flight Names  
          Flight Names  

Fare_ID | Flight Names | Departure Arrival Station | Fare

Fare_ID | Flight Names | Departure Arrival Station | Fare
          Flight Names  
          Flight Names 
          Flight Names
```

Comment: Thank you , but let me try it sir

Comment: Sir, it gives me output but not in perfect form...
i have currently 2 records in Fare table with fare_ID 1 & 2, but it just shows me only 1 record with fare_id 1 and on flight_names column , it takes both flight names and showing me both in 1 row..
Please see here
http://snag.gy/RygrO.jpg

Comment: And what's the perfect form?

Comment: i have currently 2 records in Fare table with fare_ID 1 & 2, but it just shows me only 1 record with fare_id 1 and on flight_names column , it takes both flight names and showing me both in 1 row.. Please see here snag.gy/RygrO.jpg

Comment: Humm, that shouldn't happen since it's been join by `fare.Flight_ID = flight.Flight_ID`, and looking at your MySQL they have different ID's. Create an example in SQLfiddle and post it here.

Comment: I haven't use SQL fiddle before

Comment: Ok, hold on, I'll create one as example and post it here.

Comment: My bad, forgot the `GROUP BY` clause in the query. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/54e87/1 - post edited

Comment: Hmm , let me check it sir

Comment: Like this sir..
public function getFlights()
 {
    $this->db->select('f.*, GROUP_CONCAT(fl.Flight_Name SEPARATOR "<br/>") AS `flight_names`')
             ->from('fare AS f')
             ->join('flights AS fl', 'fl.Flight_ID = f.Flight_ID', 'INNER')
             ->group_by('f.Flight_ID');
    return $this->db->get()->result();
 }

Comment: You should start calling me sir, since it's making me feel like a old guy :D. Your code is not right in the part of the `group` clause. See my edited post..

Answer (score 0):

as i understood

```
<?php foreach ($tt as $s): ?>
    <tr class="odd gradeX">
        <td><?php echo $s->Fare_ID; ?></td> //Fare_ID
        <?php foreach ($flt_nm as $ff): ?>
            <td><?php echo $ff->Flight_Name; ?> </td> //Flight Name
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <td><?php echo $s->Departure_Arrival_Station; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $s->Fare; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach;
```